# mysql insert errors... not sure what's wrong

Tags: mysql, insert, phpmyadmin

i can't figure out why this isn't working. using mysql version 5.0.91-log. and phpMyAdmin

```
INSERT INTO 'sequences'(
'key', 'author', 'tlength', 'progress', 'time')
VALUES (
NULL , '00000', 10, 1, NULL
)
```

gets the following error.

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL >server version for the right syntax to use near ''sequences'(
>   'key', 'author', 'tlength', 'progress', 'time')
>   VALUES (
>   NULL , ' at line 1

here's the table (name, type, attributes, null, default, extra)

```
key        int(11)     UNSIGNED   No                        auto_increment
author     char(20)               No        
tlength    tinyint(3)  UNSIGNED   No        
progress   tinyint(4)  UNSIGNED   No    0   
time       timestamp              Yes   CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

i've tried many combinations of the above query with/without quotes and other variations. any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two things:

- Don't quote the table name or fields
- 'Key' is a reserved word in MySQL so you need to enclose that field name with backticks

this will give you:

```
INSERT INTO sequences (
`key`, author, tlength, progress, time)
VALUES (
NULL , '00000', 10, 1, NULL
)
```

it's often easier just to quote all field names and table names with backticks just in case, but here's a full list of all the reserved words which can catch you out: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html

Answer (score 3):

By default you should not put table names in quotes. Try:

```
INSERT INTO sequences (
    'key', 'author', 'tlength', 'progress', 'time')
VALUES (
    NULL , '00000', 10, 1, NULL
)
```

Comment: There should be no quotes in column names too

Comment: as i said... i've tried with and without quotes. i'm still getting an error, with differences in the code excerpt and line number.

Comment: @Victor can you give us the error message when you try it without quotes?

Answer (score 3):

Replace the quotes with the backticks for the table and column names:

```
INSERT
INTO    `sequences` (`key`, `author`, `tlength`, `progress`, `time`)
VALUES  (NULL, '00000', 10, 1, NULL)
```

Answer (score 0):

As in most other languages, quotes are used as string delimiters, so the interpreter can distinguish a keyword from a literal. Just run this query to see the difference:

```
SELECT 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

If you quote table and column names, you are telling MySQL that they are *not* database objects.

Also, you have a column called `key`. That's a reserved word in MySQL you need to escape it. The syntax MySQL uses for such cases is the *back* quote:

```
INSERT INTO sequences (`key`, author, tlength, progress, time)
VALUES (NULL , '00000', 10, 1, NULL)
```

Last but not least, you cannot insert NULL in the `key` column if you've defined it as `NOT NULL`. That's what `NOT NULL` means.